# Adobe AIR ADT command

Tags: air

I am confused about how to use the ADT to create AIR package / applications and hope someone can help. I use CS5.5 (which includes Air 2.6 - which runs like a dog...) so I want to compile everything using my command line - AIR 3.1 install.

So I have 2 projects:

1) Which compiles to an SWC
2) The Actual application which in publish settings in CS5.5 is includes this SWC as an external library.

So how use ADT to compile this application from the command line so it uses this SWC?

Or am I misunderstanding how this works and does ADT just use the SWF and converts that to the actual package I want?

Confused from England :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the ADT command is just a package which converts your SWF/SWC's to the desired output format such as IPA.